# Transform subtables in the same table to columns

Tags: sql, database, plsql, pivot

I have a table like this:

| ID | City | Param | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | city1 | a | value |
| id2 | city1 | b | value |
| id3 | city1 | c | value |
| id4 | city2 | a | value |
| id5 | city2 | b | value |
| id6 | city2 | c | value |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| idN | cityN | a | value |
| idN+1 | cityN | b | value |
| idN+2 | cityN | c | value |

As you can see it have a subtable for each city like:

| Param | Value |
| --- | --- |
| a | value |
| b | value |
| c | value |

So I would like to join all subtables and get a table like this:

| Param | city1 | city2 | ... | cityN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | value | value | ... | value |
| b | value | value | ... | value |
| c | value | value | ... | value |

Any ideas how I can get it?

Thank you in advance!

Note1: The number of cities is variable.

Note2: The solution could be a PL/SQL function.

Comment: This is called a dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the result that you want you need to *pivot* the data.  While you said plsql could be an option, you did not specify what version of Oracle you are using.  Starting in Oracle 11g, the `PIVOT` function was made available.

If you are not using Oracle 119, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select param,
    max(case when city = 'city1' then value end) City1,
    max(case when city = 'city2' then value end) City2
from yourtable
group by param
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23d0a/1).

Since you state that you will have an unknown number of `city` values, then you will need to create a dynamic sql version of this query. You can create a procedure similar to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
    sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select param ';

    begin
        for x in (select distinct city from yourtable order by 1)
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
                ' , max(case when city = '''||x.city||''' then value else null end) as '||x.city;

                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

        sql_query := sql_query || ' from yourtable group by param order by param';
        dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);

        open p_cursor for sql_query;
    end;
/
```

Then to get your result, you can use the following (*note: I used this in TOAD*):

```
variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot(:x)
print x
```

And the result of your query will be:

```
| PARAM | CITY1 | CITY2 |
-------------------------
|     a | value | value |
|     b | value | value |
|     c | value | value |
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the new `pivot` in 11G or the `model` clause if you have 10G. 
check the docs.